# Inserting numbers to a string

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have the following string

```
std::string str = "000000"
```

and I want to run a loop from 0 to 200 and insert the numbers in the string.

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < 200; i++ )
{
    // insert number
}
```

If `i = 1`, then the string should be "000001".

If `i = 200`, then the string should be "000200".

Currently I am casting my numbers to string and than I check their length. Based on that, I insert the numbers to the string if `len = 1` and then replace the last char of the string.

Just wanted to know if I can have more refined approach to this.

Comment: please show your code. Text is not appropriate to explain code in all details, and details do matter (especially as you are asking for something "more refined"). See also: [mcve]

Comment: ..and please dont spam tags. For the current standard (C++17 i believe) you only need the C++ tag. Use the tags for specific versions of the standard only when the question is about that specific version of the standard

Comment: I recommend that you learn about [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) and the [standard I/O manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) (especially the ones for [setting the field width](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [setting fill character](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read about [std::stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/).

Following would work:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= 200; i++ ) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::setw(6) << std::setfill('0') << i;
        std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Check [live](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:'%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Csstream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciomanip%3E%0A%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++for+(int+i+%3D+0+%3B+i+%3C%3D+200%3B+i%2B%2B+)+%7B%0A++++++++std::stringstream+ss%3B%0A++++++++ss+%3C%3C+std::setw(6)+%3C%3C+std::setfill(!'0!')+%3C%3C+i%3B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+ss.str()+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:49.85494633014216,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Answer (score 3):

```
std::stringstream str;
str << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(6) << i;
```

Now `str.str()` is a string containing what you expected. You'll need to include `<sstream>`.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
std::string str = "000000";
for( int i = 0 ; i < 200; i++ )
{
    str[5] = '0' + i % 10;
    str[4] = '0' + (i/10)%10;
    str[3] = '0' + (i/100)%10;

    // presumably do something useful with str
}
```

No need for any standard headers, other than (obviously) `<string>`.

Turning the three statements into a loop left as an exercise.

Comment: Nice, Your method is very Well. Congratulations

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code:

```
std::string str = "000000";
for( int i = 0 ; i < 200; i++ )
{
    str.replace(str.length() - std::to_string(i).length(), str.length(), std::to_string(i));
    cout << str << endl;
}
```